# SQLite: error: C1083: cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h'

Tags: c++, sqlite, visual-studio-2012

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm) on how to implement SQLite in c\c++. However, when compiling the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main(int args, char* argv[]){
    sqlite *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;   
    rc = sqlite3_open("database_1.db", &db);
    if(rc){
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open databse: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      exit(0);
    }else{ 
      fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

I receive the following error: C1083: cannot open include file:'sqlite3.h': no such file or directory.

what is the problem and how to solve it.

Note: sqlite was downloaded and installed following [this guidance](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_installation.htm) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that your compiler can actually see sqlite3 includes.

In gcc you'd do something like:

```
g++ main.cpp -I<path_to_sqlite3>
```

Without "-I" parameter, your #include  cannot be seen by the compiler.

If sqlite3.h file is in the same directory as your "main.cpp" file - change your include to:

```
#include "sqlite3.h"
```

If you are unsure about the difference, please read: [Difference between #include < > and " "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

Comment: well, the full path of the folder and the "" made the difference .. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the folder with the library headers added to the Additional include directories. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx.

Comment: Thankns @Marius, but instead of adding additional include folder i just put the full path of the header file, basicaly because I am using it just once, though it is not a practical solution

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to install libsqlite3-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

Comment: can i install libsqlite3-dev on windows ?

Comment: @NathanBasanese bacause the sqlite3 is the software program, while libsqlite3 is the lib, while libsqlite3-dev are the includes.